# Connection through SSH tunnel initially slow

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have built an SSH tunneling service that runs in an Alpine based container, based on the approach outlined here: https://github.com/cagataygurturk/docker-ssh-tunnel

The service connects via IdentityFiles, and sets up multiple ControlSockets and tunnels.

I am testing this out against an Amazon Linux bastion, tunneling through to a PostgreSQL database.

SSH login and tunnel creation is correct, and the tunnels can be used, but there appears to be a timeout somewhere.

- If a tunnel - maybe the connection to the target SSH server as a whole? - has been left idle for 5 mins and then connected to, the connection process hangs for 30 secs before continuing successfully.
- Tunnel connections just after the first connection are quick - subsecond.
- Let the tunnel/server be idle for 5 mins, and the 30 sec delay comes back.

Here is the evidence:

**client ssh-config**

```
Host my-bastion
    HostName 99.99.99.99
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem

Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/cp_%r_%h
    ControlPersist yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ServerAliveCountMax 60
    ServerAliveInterval 30
    TCPKeepAlive no
    ForkAfterAuthentication yes
    StdinNull yes
    ExitOnForwardFailure yes
    IPQoS 0x00
```

**Test Workflow**

Tunnel previously established using ControlSocket.

Testing with a psql request that fails authentication, but exercises the tunnel.

psql makes 2 connections through the tunnel during the test.

*First access after at least 5 mins idle.*

```
# date && time psql "host=localhost port=5430 dbname=xxx user=UUU password=X"
Tue Mar  8 12:10:57 PST 2022
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "UUU"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "UUU"

real    0m32.497s - slow!
```

*SSH client log -vv*

```
1st psql request

[2022-03-08 20:10:57] debug1: Connection to port 5430 forwarding to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 requested.
[2022-03-08 20:10:57] debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]

30 sec Delay here
[2022-03-08 20:10:57] debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768

[2022-03-08 20:11:29] debug2: channel 3: read<=0 rfd 7 len 0


2nd psql request

[2022-03-08 20:11:29] debug1: Connection to port 5430 forwarding to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 requested.
[2022-03-08 20:11:29] debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]

subsecond response on channel 4

[2022-03-08 20:11:29] debug2: channel 4: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768

[2022-03-08 20:11:29] debug2: channel 4: read<=0 rfd 8 len 0
```

*Access immediately after 1st.*

```
# date && time psql "host=localhost port=5430 dbname=xxx user=UUU password=X"
Tue Mar  8 12:11:41 PST 2022
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "UUU"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "UUU"

real    0m0.874s - fast!
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.016s

1st psql request

[2022-03-08 20:11:41] debug1: Connection to port 5430 forwarding to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 requested.
[2022-03-08 20:11:41] debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
[2022-03-08 20:11:41] debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
[2022-03-08 20:11:41] debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]

Subsecond response to request

[2022-03-08 20:11:41] debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768

[2022-03-08 20:11:42] debug2: channel 3: read<=0 rfd 7 len 0

...

2nd psql request

[2022-03-08 20:11:42] debug1: Connection to port 5430 forwarding to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 requested.
[2022-03-08 20:11:42] debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]

[2022-03-08 20:11:42] debug2: channel 4: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
```

I have searched for others with this issue, but have not found this problem being talked about. I have tried advice from https://jrs-s.net/2017/07/01/slow-ssh-logins/ and set IpQos=0x00 to work around any potential router issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless service I was tunneling to. The default setting for Serverless is to pause the cluster when there is 5 mins of inactivity. When a new connection comes in, the service takes 30 secs or so to restart.

So the slow connection after 5 mins was the Serverless service restarting, not an SSH issue at all :-/